# Can std::span iterators outlive the span object they are created from?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, lifetime, std-span

Put it other way, conversely, are `std::span` iterators invalidated after the span instance is destroyed?

I have a vector I need to iterate over with different layouts. I'm trying to make use of `std::span` to avoid writing a lot of iterator boilerplate or bringing in an external library dependency. Simplified example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

template <size_t N>
struct my_view {
  std::vector<int> vec;

  auto as_span() {
    return std::span<int[N]>((int(*)[N])vec.data(), vec.size() / N);
  }

  auto begin() {
    return as_span().begin();
  }

  auto end() {
    return as_span().end();
  }
};

int main() {
  std::vector vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  my_view<2> pairs {std::move(vec)};
  for (auto pair : pairs) {
    std::cout << pair[0] << " " << pair[1] << std::endl;
  }
  my_view<3> triplets {std::move(pairs.vec)};
  for (auto triplet : triplets) {
    std::cout << triplet[0] << " " << triplet[1] << " " << triplet[2] << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n1djETane

Comment: I was not able to find normative text around this. In theory, they should be able to outlive the span (since the span itself holds no data members beside the pointer to underlying sequence, and a size for dynamic extents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I appreciate that this question asks both the positive and negative version of the same question consecutively. Thus...

> Can `std::span` iterators outlive the span object they are created from?

Yes.

> Are `std::span` iterators invalidated after the span instance is destroyed?

No.

This is why you in [[span.syn]](https://eel.is/c++draft/span.syn) you see:

```cpp
template<class ElementType, size_t Extent>
  inline constexpr bool ranges::enable_borrowed_range<span<ElementType, Extent>> = true;
```

Where, from [[range.range]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/ranges#range.range-5):

> Given an expression `E` such that `decltype((E))` is `T`, `T` models `borrowed_­range` only if the validity of iterators obtained from the object denoted by `E` is not tied to the lifetime of that object.

> [*Note 2*: Since the validity of iterators is not tied to the lifetime of an object whose type models `borrowed_­range`, a function can accept arguments of such a type by value and return iterators obtained from it without danger of dangling. — *end note*]

Were a `span`'s iterators to be tied to the lifetime of the `span`, it would be invalid to do this -- `span` would have to be non-borrowed (as, e.g., `vector<T>` clearly is not borrowed).

---

`gsl::span`'s iterators used to keep a pointer to the `span` (which would obviously cause the iterators to be invalidated), but that was changed [in Feb 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/pull/844) (I have not looked through the comments to find the discussion there, but that one matches the standard behavior).

Comment: Appreciated. I intended to paraphrase same question to keep it search engine friendly but the inversion was rather unintentional. Let me throw a "conversely" over there to clarify.

Comment: @ofo I just found it funny cause I started typing Yes. And then went back and realized that that was wrong, and then put No. And then realized that it was both :-)